# Digital story in Charterstone

Tags: charterstone

One element of the board game version of [Charterstone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.acram.Charterstone) is that you build up a story in the rule book based on the choices you make throughout the series of games.

Is there a way to see this consolidated story in the App versions?